# Replace value of a variable which is read from file inside another script

Tags: shell-script

I have a config file `xyz.cfg` which has below values

```
NewYork|US|NewYork_${CUT_NO}_
Delhi|INDIA|Delhi_${CUT_NO}_
```

I have a script `housekeeping.sh` which has global variables

```
CUT_NO=001
```

and using `while` I am reading the `xyz.cfg` file.

But after reading the line, `${CUT_NO}` is not getting replaced

o/p should be `NewYork_001_`
but I am getting `NewYork_${CUT_NO}_`.

Comment: This is a Q&A site. It is appropriate to inclue a clearly stated, grammatically correct, interrogative sentence in your post. Please read the [tour], follow its advice, and update your post.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` to replace the placeholder in the file with the value of the variable:

```
sed "s/\${CUT_NO}/$CUT_NO/" xyz.cfg
```

Then read the `|`-delimited output from `sed`:

```
sed "s/\${CUT_NO}/$CUT_NO/" xyz.cfg |
while IFS='|' read c1 c2 c3; do
  printf 'Column 3 has value "%s"\n' "$c3"
done
```

or

```
sed "s/\${CUT_NO}/$CUT_NO/" xyz.cfg |
awk -F '|' '{ printf("Column 3 has value \"%s\"\n", $3) }'
```

or something similar.

This results in

```
Column 3 has value "NewYork_001_"  
Column 3 has value "Delhi_001_"
```

---

The shell variable in the file, if not replaced by the value of the variable in your script, will be read as any other text.  This is why you get `NewYork_${CUT_NO}_`.

An alternative way of doing this would be to pass the string `NewYork_${CUT_NO}_` through `eval printf '%s\n' "$c3"'` (if the string is stored as `$c3`) and assign the value back to `c3` or to a new variable, but `eval` is generally not considered safe for evaluating user-supplied data (for example, say the last column had the value `NewYork_${CUT_NO}_;ls -l` or something more dangerous).